# SQL query to sort based on two column values (creating a calculated field in SQL)

Tags: php, sql, ms-access

I'm currently porting SQL queries into PHP to interact directly with an access DB.

What I need to do is sort a field if the value of column 1 is greater than zero and if not sort the field based on the text description of column 2. I already have this as a calculated field in Access sorted Ascending and hidden but the direct port to SQL isn't working.

In Access it looks like:

```
IIf((Round(SLA.SLA-SLAMins)/60,2))>0,'A' 
       & Format(999999-(Round(SLA.SLA-SLAMins)/60,2)),'000000.00'),'B000000.00') 
       & Left([SrFreetext],10)
```

Any ideas on how I can keep the calculated field for sorting purposes?

Answer (score 0):

I usually solve this through a union. Without a schema, I can't give you a precise answer, but it's something like:

```
select *, 
       1 as sortingColumn
from  tableName
where Round(SLA.SLA-SLAMins)/60,2))>0
union
select *, 
       0 as sortingColumn
from   tableName
where  Round(SLA.SLA-SLAMins)/60,2)) <= 0
order by sortingColumn, textDescriptionField
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll give it a go. I did try a Union initially when I was building the query but it caused me some grief which is why I went on to make the calculated field to sort on.

Comment: Hey Neville, Just remembered why I didn't use a union before. I was puling the data via ODBC and it didn't like the union query. Working on the syntax now but still not quite there